# Background resized by Navigationbar

Tags: android

i am developing an Android App and want to use a picture as background in my Activity. On devices without the Navigationbar (Devices with a Homebutton) it looks great. When the device has no hardware buttons, Android scales the backgroundpicture because the height of the screen is reduced by the Actionbar.
My Question is not about xhdpi, hdpi and so on, but about handling for 16:9, 16:10...

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

How are you specifying the background image in your layout? If you are using an `android:background` attribute on a View then you will have no control over image scaling. It sounds like this is what you are doing.

Instead create an ImageView with appropriate scale type. For example I use the following structure:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />
    <!-- Rest of your layout  -->
</FrameLayout>
```